# Localhost database connect from other sysytem

Tags: html, ajax, http

I am testing a website which in other machine like 192.168.0.1 in my machine which is 127.168.0.2 so in the website ajax jquery is used on page load in which the url is

```
http://localhost/Demo/store.php
```

but when i execute that page in website in other machine the database isnt connecting and even if i give the url as

```
http://192.168.0.1/Demo/store.php
```

its not connecting to database..What is the issue please tell me...How can i access from other system so that all my local database values can be displayed in other machines also..Thanx..

Comment: rephrase your question into a bit readable sentences, and show us parts of your code please

Answer (score 0):

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940018.aspx:

> address 127 .x.y.z is reserved for loopback testing and interprocess communication on the local computer.

Your probably not connected to your network correctly. Check your physical connection (blinking leds), then make sure you have a DHCP server on the network, otherwise assign a static IP.

After this try pinging the address to make sure the 2 hosts can see each other. Also open up any ports which may be behind a firewall, 3306 is default for MySQL DB.